# Dynamics AX Modify Standard Report Data Set

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Good day,

I am new to dynamics AX and I need to modify a report which is `ReturnAcknowledgmentAndDocumentReport`. I found the report design under `AOT > Visual Studio Projects > Dynamics AX Model Projects`.

[image]

I opened this in visual studio and I saw that the report data set used is `ReturnAcknowledgmentAndDocumentDS`. Now I am unable to find this data set under `AOT > Data Sets`.

Currently I am under the usr layer. I haven't configured my environment to use the cus layer yet and I don't know if this affects the objects visible in the AOT.

My main goal is to add the item batch number and expiration date on the return order print out. Since the data set doesn't seem to contain the fields I need, I plan to modify this.

Please let me know how to modify this data set. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to Dynamics AX, you should take a look at some training, e.g. the development I - IV series. Part IV includes an introduction to reporting. To start with the modification of a standard report without this training is ... challenging.

Although identical in name, the data sets in SSRS reports and the data sets in the AOT are used for different purposes and have nothing in common.

The layer does not affect visibility of objects in the AOT.

The `ReturnAcknowledgmentAndDocumentReport` uses a data provider class for its data set, so to reach your goal you would have to modify class `ReturnAcknowledgmentAndDocumentDP` and the corresponding `ReturnAcknowledgmentAndDocumentTmp` table.

Further reading:

- [Walkthrough: Customizing Existing Microsoft Dynamics AX Reports](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc567629.aspx)
- [How to: Define a Report Dataset](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc621410.aspx)
- [How to: Use a Report Data Provider Class in a Report](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731917.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've already finished Development I to III. Development IV is not available to me at the moment. I will ask for this later.